# Having trouble reading table using sqldf package (R)

Tags: r, sqldf, read.csv

**Background:**

I can successfully pull a particular dataset (shown in the code below) from the internet using the `read.csv()` function.  However, when I try to utilize the `sqldf` package to speed up the process using `read.csv.sql()` it produces errors.  I've tried various solutions but can't seem to solve this problem.

I can successfully pull the data and create the data frame that I want with `read.csv()` using the following code:

```
ce_data <- read.csv("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cx/cx.data.1.AllData", 
                     fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, sep="")
```

To test the functionality of `sqldf` on my machine, I successfully tested `read.csv.sql()` by reading in the data as 1 variable rather than the 5 desired using the following code:

```
library(sqldf)

ce_data_sql1 <- read.csv.sql("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cx/cx.data.1.AllData", 
                         sql = "select * from file")
```

To produce the result that I got using `read.csv()` but utilizing the speed of `read.csv.sql()`, I tried this code:

```
ce_data_sql2 <- read.csv.sql("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cx/cx.data.1.AllData", 
                             fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, sep="", sql = "select * from file")
```

Unfortunately, it produced this error:

> trying URL
>   'http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cx/cx.data.1.AllData' Content
>   type 'text/plain' length 24846571 bytes (23.7 MB) downloaded 23.7 MB
>
> Error in sqldf(sql, envir = p, file.format = file.format, dbname =
>   dbname,  :    unused argument (fill = TRUE)

I have tried various methods to address the errors, using `sqldf` documentation and have been unsuccessful.

**Question:**

Is there a solution where I can read in this table with 5 variables desired using `read.csv.sql`()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are reading it in as a single variable is because you did not correctly specify the separator for the original file. **Try the following, where `sep = "\t"`, for tab-separated:**

```
ce_data_sql2 <- read.csv.sql("http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/cx/cx.data.1.AllData", 
sep = "\t", sql = "select * from file")
```

.

The error you are getting in the final example:

> Error in sqldf(sql, envir = p, file.format = file.format, dbname =
>   dbname, : unused argument (fill = TRUE)

Is due to the fact that `read.csv.sql` does not accept the `fill` argument.

Comment: Thanks very much, @eleventhend